# Listview- clicking on the title to show the description

Tags: java, android, listview

Im doing Dream app on Android. I have a ListView view containing a title and description that are stored in separate TextView. I want the titles to be displayed in the listView view and only after clicking one of them to display the description. After pressing another title, I want the previous description to collapse and show another, attached to the given title.

I want to my notes look this way:
[Android dream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JkON.png)

This is my adapter class where I think I need to add a few lines to solve my problem

```
class SennikListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<Sennik> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
private ArrayList<Sennik> mDisplayedValues;    // Values to be displayed
LayoutInflater inflater;


public SennikListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Sennik> mProductArrayList) {
    this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
    this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDisplayedValues.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout llContainer;
    TextView titleOfDream, descriptionOfDream;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
        holder.llContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
        holder.titleOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        holder.descriptionOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.titleOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getTitleOfDream());
    holder.descriptionOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getDescriptionOfDream() + "");

    return convertView;
}
```

I wanted to do something like this in getView method, but there is an error "Veriable 'holder' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declered final". If i change to final still doesn't work

```
  holder.titleOfDream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.descriptionOfDream.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                //expandedChildList.set(arg2, true);
                holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                //expandedChildList.set(arg2, false);
                holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Do you have any ideas how to do this? I checked so many tutorials but didn't find, and im sure it isn't difficult :(

Maybe this would be helpful
this is Fragment class

```
public class SennikFragment extends Fragment {

private List<String> fileName;
private List<String> fileContent;
private ArrayList<Sennik> sen = new ArrayList<Sennik>();
private SennikListAdapter adapter;
private EditText editText;
private ListView listView;
private AssetManager assets;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sennik, container, false);

    // inicjalizacja pól
    fileName = new ArrayList<>();
    fileContent = new ArrayList<>();
    editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
    listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    assets = getActivity().getAssets();

    //dodanie do pola wyszukiwania obiektu nasłuchującego zmian w tekście
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d("filter", "no filter availible");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    //uzupełnienie listy tytułów i opisów snu z folderu assets
    try {
        //Pobranie nazw wszystkich plików
        String[] paths = assets.list("");
        String text="";

        /* Usunięcie z nazw plików ich rozszerzenia formatu */
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (path.equals("images") || path.equals("sounds") || path.equals("webkit"))
                continue;
            fileName.add(path.replace(".txt", "  "));
            InputStream is= assets.open(path);
            int size=is.available();
            byte[]buffer=new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text=new String(buffer);
            fileContent.add(text);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bład podczas ładowania plików", ex);
    }

    //dodanie do listy z modelu Sennik tytułów i opisów snu
    for(int i=0; i<fileName.size(); i++){
         sen.add(new Sennik(fileName.get(i), fileContent.get(i)));
    }

    adapter=new SennikListAdapter((Context)getActivity(),sen);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

this is description class

```
public class Sennik {
private String titleOfDream;
private String descriptionOfDream;

public Sennik(String titleOfDream, String descriptionOfDream) {
    this.titleOfDream = titleOfDream;
    this.descriptionOfDream = descriptionOfDream;
}

public String getTitleOfDream() {
    return titleOfDream;
}

public void setTitleOfDream(String titleOfDream) {
    this.titleOfDream = titleOfDream;
}

public String getDescriptionOfDream() {
    return descriptionOfDream;
}

public void setDescriptionOfDream(String descriptionOfDream) {
    this.descriptionOfDream = descriptionOfDream;
}
```

}
and my layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/llContainer">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchFilter"></EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchFilter">


</ListView>
```

EDIT
problem solved!
I just add a line to my Adapter class to hide the description

```
holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

so the whole Adapter class look like:

```
class SennikListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<Sennik> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
private ArrayList<Sennik> mDisplayedValues;    // Values to be displayed
LayoutInflater inflater;


public SennikListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Sennik> mProductArrayList) {
    this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
    this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDisplayedValues.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout llContainer;
    TextView titleOfDream, descriptionOfDream;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;


    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
        holder.llContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
        holder.titleOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        holder.descriptionOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.titleOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getTitleOfDream());
    holder.descriptionOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getDescriptionOfDream() + "");
    holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;

}
```

And in Fragment class i use setOnItemClickListener method on listView (setOnClickListener doesn't work)

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView descriptionOfDream= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
            if(descriptionOfDream.getVisibility()==view.GONE){
                descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }

        }
    });
```

So the whole Fragment class look like:

```
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sennik, container, false);

    // inicjalizacja pól
    fileName = new ArrayList<>();
    fileContent = new ArrayList<>();
    editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
    listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    assets = getActivity().getAssets();

    //dodanie do pola wyszukiwania obiektu nasłuchującego zmian w tekście
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d("filter", "no filter availible");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    //uzupełnienie listy tytułów i opisów snu z folderu assets
    try {
        //Pobranie nazw wszystkich plików
        String[] paths = assets.list("");
        String text="";

        /* Usunięcie z nazw plików ich rozszerzenia formatu */
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (path.equals("images") || path.equals("sounds") || path.equals("webkit"))
                continue;
            fileName.add(path.replace(".txt", "  "));
            InputStream is= assets.open(path);
            int size=is.available();
            byte[]buffer=new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text=new String(buffer);
            fileContent.add(text);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bład podczas ładowania plików", ex);
    }

    //dodanie do listy z modelu Sennik tytułów i opisów snu
    for(int i=0; i<fileName.size(); i++){
         sen.add(new Sennik(fileName.get(i), fileContent.get(i)));
    }

    adapter=new SennikListAdapter((Context)getActivity(),sen);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView descriptionOfDream= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
            if(descriptionOfDream.getVisibility()==view.GONE){
                descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Works excelent <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call this method in your code`

```
holder.descriptionOfDream.requestLayout();
```

So basically, your new code looks like this

```
holder.titleOfDream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (holder.descriptionOfDream.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        {
            //expandedChildList.set(arg2, true);
            holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.descriptionOfDream.requestLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            //expandedChildList.set(arg2, false);
            holder.descriptionOfDream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.descriptionOfDream.requestLayout();
        }

    }
});
```

Hope that helps.
**Keep in mind that the holder variable must be final like below**

```
final ViewHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
    holder.llContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
    holder.titleOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    holder.descriptionOfDream = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.titleOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getTitleOfDream());
holder.descriptionOfDream.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getDescriptionOfDream() + "");

return convertView;
```

Comment: still the same error :( But i was checked if i remove holder and just initialize the text views without holder and debug the app, it doesn't even step into clicklistener... Im confused

Comment: @Kornelia the holder variable must be final to prevent errors

Comment: problem solved! I will paste code in EDIT part of my question :D

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a class Extending LinearLayout and give some Expanding/collapsing 
capabilities to It. Then define your description Textview as a child of that.

```
public class ExpandableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
private boolean expanded;
private int duration;

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public ExpandableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    TypedArray customValues = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.ExpandableLinearLayout);
    duration = customValues.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableLinearLayout_expandDuration, -1);
    customValues.recycle();
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}

public void toggle() {
    if (expanded)
        expandView(this);
    else
        hideView(this);
}

private void expandView(final View view) {
    view.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            , MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    final int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    view.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            view.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? targetHeight : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            view.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    if (duration == -1)
        a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1.5));
    else
        a.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(a);
}

private void hideView(final View view) {
    final int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                view.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    if (duration == -1)
        a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / view.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1.5));
    else
        a.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(a);
}

}
```

Just Inflate this class into your xml layout file and create descriotion textView inside of it.

Add The following Code snippet into your Adapter class to call that when An Item gets a Click. It will Expand/Collapse the LinearLayout with an Animaiton.

```
 private void initializeClicks() {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (expandableLinearLayout.isExpanded()) {
                    expandableLinearLayout.setExpanded(false);
                    expandableLinearLayout.toggle();
                    orderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setExpanded(false);
                } else {
                    expandableLinearLayout.setExpanded(true);
                    orderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setExpanded(true);
                    expandableLinearLayout.toggle();
                    if(lastExpandedCardPosition!=getAdapterPosition() && recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition)!=null){
                        ((ExpandableLinearLayout)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition).itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandedLinearLayout)).setExpanded(false);
                        orderList.get(lastExpandedCardPosition).setExpanded(false);
                        ((ExpandableLinearLayout)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition).itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandedLinearLayout)).toggle();
                    }
                    else if(lastExpandedCardPosition!=getAdapterPosition() && recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastExpandedCardPosition)==null){
                        orderList.get(lastExpandedCardPosition).setExpanded(false);
                    }
                    lastExpandedCardPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Finally call the Method above in your Clicklistenr like this:

```
 holder.titleOfDream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (holder.descriptionOfDream.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        {
              expandableLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              expandableLinearLayout.setExpanded(true);
        }
        else
        {
            expandableLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            expandableLinearLayout.setExpanded(false);
        }

    }
});
```

For a more detailed Explanation about this Method see [this](https://medium.com/@sourabhgupta_49508/android-expandable-recyclerview-e5e8465cbb86) post on Medium.com.

And dont forget to give a clap to this post.